# How to ignore events in html table

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, dom-events

I have a transparent table with width:100% which contains some html content.
I use the table in order to position a content element on the screen center.

The table captures mouse events, and the user can't press on links which are positioned beneath it (although it is transparent).

Is there a way to tell the browser to ignore events on the table?
I want to capture events only from the content inside the table (and from the rest of the site).

Comment: Why don't you just use CSS for that? That's the proper way. You see that using tables causing dozens of problems.

Comment: dude atleast accept the answers. 33% of accept is a shame..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an HTML `<table>` is the *wrong* way to position an element in the center of the screen. Use proper CSS positioning.

For positioning text use: `text-align: center;`. For positioning block elements use:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

That is not only the correct way to do things (CSS2 standard supported in all modern browsers), it will also solve your issue of captured events.

Comment: To be fair, *vertical* centering with nothing but CSS is a real pain.

Comment: @Pointy - not to say that it's not difficult, but it is very much possible.